# error code of 80020006 while installing app

Tags: 8.1, store

I'm getting the error code `80020006` while installing an app from the store. I' not able to install any app from the store, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

That error indicates a problem with COM, where a function can't be found in an interface. It's discussed [here](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/c3/268736.html), if you want to do a little reading. On windows Phone, it seems to most commonly occur in apps that use WebBrowser controls with JavaScript callbacks. If you're getting it in the Store, though, that suggests something wrong with the OS.

In that case, I'm afraid the only suggestion I can offer is to hard-reset the phone. Back up as much of your data as possible first. The contents of the SD card (if you have one) won't be wiped, except for any apps installed to the SD card, but all other personal data on the phone will be. You can back up many settings and configuration data, plus SMS and some other data, to the cloud, then restore it once the phone has been reset.